# Como eu faço para ancora aparecer em baixo do menu?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Gostaria de saber como eu faço pra âncora ficar em baixo do menu quando ela for clicada.
Meu menu é fixo com *jquery* quando ele desce alguns pixels. Por exemplo olhem essa imagem, quando eu clico na ancora o menu fica em baixo dela:

[image]

Eu gostaria que ficasse assim quando clicar na ancora:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui é o site upado no servidor para testes, caso queiram ver www.asbesc.org.br, só ir em quem somos e clicar em nossa organização, abaixo segue os codigos.

Acho que não vai ser util esse da ancora, mas só por precaução.

```
<a name="nossa-organizacao"></a> 
            <h4>Nossa organização</h4>

            <p>Trabalhamos com as comunidades de regiões mais carentes e vulneráveis, independentemente da sua origem étnica, língua, religião ou geografia.</p>

            <p>Acreditamos, acima de tudo, num mundo sem pobreza e injustiça onde o desenvolvimento humano seja equitativo e sustentável à escala local e global.</p>

            <p>Desde a Emergência ao Desenvolvimento, passando pela Educação, Mobilização 
            Social e Influência Pública, o trabalho da ASBESC estende-se atualmente para a cidade de São Paulo. Desde a fundação há 12 anos, a ASBESC já trabalhou em vários bairros da periferia da cidade de São Paulo.</p>

            <p>Somos cidadãos solidários, com uma consciência clara do papel da cidadania para a promoção da equidade na erradicação do analfabetismo e da pobreza extrema e na redução das assimetrias econômicas e do conhecimento que caracterizam a realidade mundial.</p>

            <p>A nossa atividade encontra-se estruturada nas áreas da educação, desenvolvimento/vida sustentável. Através da nossa ação, com os diferentes atores sociais (Comunidades, Governos e Sociedade Civil local, Setor Privado, Academia), partilhamos esforços e responsabilidades e facilitamos soluções para garantir que todas as pessoas usufruam do direito a uma vida digna.</p>
```

JS:

```
    /* Menu fixo ao rolar a página */
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {

            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { /* quando a página descer 100 pixels */

                $('nav#menu').css({ /* a sua div */
                    position: 'fixed', 
                    top: '43px' /* vai ficar fixa a 73 pixels do topo */
                });


            } else {

                $('nav#menu').css({
                    position: 'relative', 
                    top: '0px'
                });

            }
        });
```

Comment: `top: '43px'` já tentou mudar esse valor para `0px`? Se sim e o menu sumiu, tente apenas diminuir para `20px`

Comment: Sim já tentei, porém o menu fica em cima da ancora

Comment: É só subir o ancora ;)

Comment: Como assim subir a ancora?

Comment: Por exemplo: `<a href="">d</a><a href="">e</a><a href="">f</a><a href="">g</a><div id="ancora"></div>` -> no exemplo usei a ancora no ID DA DIV, ai pra subir a âncora é só passar a div pra cima ficando assim -> `<div id="ancora"></div><a href="">d</a><a href="">e</a><a href="">f</a><a href="">g</a>`